# What is the best cutoff wheel material to cut titanium?

Tags: materials, machining, material-science

I want to thin titanium rods about 1/2in thick quickly. I've heard silicon carbide and diamond tipped masonry wheels are good. Which is better, less prone to wear/replacement, fastest cutting time?

Answer (score 1):

With modern cutting grits being so good, even the common ones, the binder used in the cutoff wheel is more important than the cutting grit used. For harder or stronger materials you want a soft binder so the wheel wears away quickly so that it constantly exposes fresh cutting grit.

A harder binder is used for cutting lower tensile strength materials since the grit dulls more slowly so you don't need toe expose fresh grit as quickly. That's what separates a cutoff wheel that uses silicon carbide made to cut titanium, stainless, and hardened steel, versus one used for cutting aluminum.

Diamond is not typically used for titanium. Why are you looking at masonry stuff anyways? Are you only limited to stuff you can get from the hardware store? Because if you're really looking for something optimal then you need to look at an actual metalworking catalog.

Also, coolant. Coolant will make the biggest difference here. But coolant might not play nice with the integrity of a cutoff wheel. Make sure to check.